# Transfer WordPress from live server to localhost

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to transfer all my files from the remote server to my localhost. I've downloaded everything from `ftp` and exported the database(`.gzip`). I've logged in to my local `phpmyadmin` and changed the url in the `'wp_options'` table.

My problem is that when I try to run it in the browser, it redirects to my live site.

Note: I've also deleted my `.htaccess` file thinking that it may have caused the redirection.

Comment: did you change the value of siteurl and home in wp_options table?

Comment: Your site using any plugin for redirection?

Comment: @Vidhu, yes everything points to my localhost

Comment: also check you wp-config.php

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Wordpress serialized pho search replace tool, link [here](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases), to replace the live URL to the local URL. That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Plugin WP Migrate DB. It saved me hours of work, editing my databases by hand.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

> WP Migrate DB exports your database as a MySQL data dump (much like phpMyAdmin), does a find and replace on URLs and file paths, then allows you to save it to your computer. It is perfect for developers who need to update their local install with fresh data from the production site, or copy their locally developed site to a staging or production server.

It even takes into account serialized data (both arrays and objects) and updates the string length values.

It lets you define your new doc-root and urls and provides you with a finished sql file to import on your local DB.

For a quick and dirty workaround, you could add following lines of code to your wp-config.php file. But, if you remove these lines again in the future, your change of URL will disappear too.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Note: This solution only works on single-install site.

More on this topic here: [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Comment: @Harvey Katrina Did it work out? Would you mind accepting any answer here so this gets resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use searchreplacedb2.php file which can download from here

http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

and copy php file in wordpress root directory.

Then execute this file in browser and follow step by step process.

Answer (score 0):

After export your DB to gzip, unpack the file. Replace all urls of your remote example.com with localsite.com. Pack edited to gzip again. Import it with phpmyadmin.

Answer (score -1):

I think this way may help you.

go to your local admin panel and go to settings > permalinks.

and save it, then enjoy your site on localhost.

Thanks